# How to combine white background of a table with styleColorbar of a column in datatable?

Tags: r, datatable

I know how to format the background of a datatable to white:

```
formatStyle(names(mtcars), background = '#fff')
```

and how to add a `styleColorbar`as can be seen in the demo code below, but together they fail. How to combine the both? I now end up with colorbars, but a white blue alternating background again for the target column...

[image]

```
datatable(mtcars, escape=FALSE , rownames = F,
          options = list(dom = 't', 
                         pageLength = 100)) %>%
    formatStyle(names(mtcars), background = '#fff') %>% formatStyle('cyl',
                                                                         background = styleColorBar(range(mtcars$cyl), '#339fff'),
                                                                         backgroundSize = '98% 88%',
                                                                         backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat',
                                                                         backgroundPosition = 'center')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the contributors of DT package on github: 
This is one workaround to do it

```
datatable(
  mtcars, escape=FALSE , rownames = F,
  options = list(dom = 't', pageLength = 100),
  callback = JS("tmp = table.$('tr').css('background-color', '#fff');")
) %>%
  formatStyle(
    'cyl',
    background = styleColorBar(range(mtcars$cyl), '#339fff'),
    backgroundSize = '98% 88%',
    backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat',
    backgroundPosition = 'center'
  )
```